# How to parse data into C++ Struct with boost spirit if I have an "or" ('|') in my grammar

Tags: c++, struct, boost-spirit

I have the following C++ Struct:

```
struct Dimension {
    enum Type { PARENT, CHILD, PIXEL };

    Type mWidth_type = Type::PIXEL;
    int mWidth = 0;

    Type mHeight_type = Type::PIXEL;
    int mHeight = 0;
};
```

My grammar looks like this:

```
+(char_ - "{") >> "{" >>
-(lit("width") >> ":" >> (int_ | lit("_parent") | lit("_child")) >> ";") >>
-(lit("height") >> ":" >> (int_ | lit("_parent") | lit("_child")) >> ";") >>
"}"
```

I have a hierarchical structure, where some nodes might take the width or/and height of the parent or child node. So in my logic I check each node's Dimension type first. If it is PIXEL I get the value, otherwise I ask the value form the parent or child node. Because of this in my file I can have the following possibilities (same for height):

```
width: 10;
```

In this case, I want to leave Type with the default enum PIXEL and set the value for mWidth.

or

```
widht: _parent;
```

In this case, I want to set Type to PARENT and leave mWidth on default 0.

or

```
width: _child;
```

In this case, I want to set Type to CHILD and leave mWidth on default 0.

How can I parse this into a Struct? If my dimensions could take only numbers, then I would be able to proceed, but I am stuck because this is a different case. Any hints, ideas, help is much appreciated!

EDIT1:

Here is an example of the text file which needs to be parsed into the above Struct:

```
.struct1 {
    width: 12;
    height: 50;
}

.struct2 {
    width: _parent;
    height: 50;
}

.struct3 {
    width: 40;
    height: _child;
}

.struct4 {
    width: _parent;
    height: _child;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you include a self conatined example? Not many people will be motivated to concoct the grammar for you

Comment: You mean I should add an example of the text file which needs to be parsed in the above Struct? If so I edited the question and added an example!

Comment: TBH I meant the code. It's knows as a http://sscce.org or [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Oh, sorry for the miss understanding! I didn't had too much code just the grammar, because I didn't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest to factor the AST type so as to not repeat yourself:

```
struct Dimension {
    struct Value {
        enum Type { PARENT, CHILD, PIXEL } type;
        int value;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Value const& v) {
            switch(v.type) {
                case PARENT: return os << "[PARENT:" << v.value << "]";
                case CHILD:  return os << "[CHILD:"  << v.value << "]";
                case PIXEL:  return os << "[PIXEL:"  << v.value << "]";
            }
            return os << "?";
        }
    };

    Value mWidth, mHeight;
};
```

Adapt it for fusion:

```
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Dimension::Value, (Dimension::Value::Type, type)(int, value))
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Dimension, (Dimension::Value, mWidth)(Dimension::Value, mHeight))
```

Now, I'd write the grammar to match:

```
    start   = width_ ^ height_;
    width_  = lit("width")  >> ':' >> value_ >> ';';
    height_ = lit("height") >> ':' >> value_ >> ';';

    value_  =
        ( "_child"  >> attr(Dimension::Value::CHILD)  >> attr(0)
        | "_parent" >> attr(Dimension::Value::PARENT) >> attr(0)
        | eps       >> attr(Dimension::Value::PIXEL)  >> int_
        );
```

Note:

- you could use the permutation parser to be more versatile
- you can see the use of `attr` to inject attributes so the branches all synthesize a `vector2<Type, int>`

Adding debugging and a few test cases:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c4dce047fe9e586)</kbd>**

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

struct Dimension {
    struct Value {
        enum Type { PARENT, CHILD, PIXEL } type;
        int value;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Value const& v) {
            switch(v.type) {
                case PARENT: return os << "[PARENT:" << v.value << "]";
                case CHILD:  return os << "[CHILD:"  << v.value << "]";
                case PIXEL:  return os << "[PIXEL:"  << v.value << "]";
            }
            return os << "?";
        }
    };

    Value mWidth, mHeight;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Dimension::Value, (Dimension::Value::Type, type)(int, value))
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Dimension, (Dimension::Value, mWidth)(Dimension::Value, mHeight))

template <typename It, typename Skipper>
struct grammar : qi::grammar<It, Dimension(), Skipper>
{
    grammar() : grammar::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi;

        start   = width_ ^ height_;
        width_  = lit("width")  >> ':' >> value_ >> ';';
        height_ = lit("height") >> ':' >> value_ >> ';';
        value_  =
            ( "_child"  >> attr(Dimension::Value::CHILD)  >> attr(0)
            | "_parent" >> attr(Dimension::Value::PARENT) >> attr(0)
            | eps       >> attr(Dimension::Value::PIXEL)  >> int_
            );

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(value_)(width_)(height_))
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<It, Dimension(), Skipper> start;
    qi::rule<It, Dimension::Value(), Skipper> value_, width_, height_;
};

int main() {
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    grammar<It, qi::space_type> p;

    for (std::string const input : {
            "width: 10;      height: _child;",
            "width: _parent; height: 10;",
            "width: _child;  height: 10;"
            })
    {
        It f = input.begin(), l = input.end();
        std::cout << "\n-----------------------------------\n"
                  << "Parsing '" << input << "'\n";

        Dimension parsed;
        bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, p, qi::space, parsed);

        if (ok)
            std::cout << "Parsed: (" << parsed.mWidth << "x" << parsed.mHeight << ")\n";
        else
            std::cout << "Parse failed\n";

        if (f!=l)
            std::cout << "Remaining input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Output (without debug information):

```
-----------------------------------
Parsing 'width: 10;      height: _child;'
Parsed: ([PIXEL:10]x[CHILD:0])

-----------------------------------
Parsing 'width: _parent; height: 10;'
Parsed: ([PARENT:0]x[PIXEL:10])

-----------------------------------
Parsing 'width: _child;  height: 10;'
Parsed: ([CHILD:0]x[PIXEL:10])
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much! Really nice and detailed answer, from this I think I will be able to mange to extend it for even more complex parsers!